# Dispatch_Group crash on iPhone 4s/iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've written a method using `dispatch_group` :

```
class func loadNewEvents(inContext context:NSManagedObjectContext, completion:(() -> Void)?=nil) {
    DDLogDebug("Loading New Events")
    let context = CoreDataManager.backgroundContext()
    let events = CoreDataManager.fetch(Event.self, inContext: context)
    var earliestEvent = events.sort({$0.initialTimestamp.integerValue > $1.initialTimestamp.integerValue}).first

    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    var loadedEvents:[Event]?
    var failure = false
    while (loadedEvents == nil || loadedEvents!.count != 0) && !failure {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        if let earliestTimeStamp = earliestEvent?.initialTimestamp.longLongValue {
            let url = afterUrl(earliestTimeStamp)
            getEvents(url: url,
                success: { events in
                    loadedEvents = events
                    earliestEvent = events.last
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                },
                failure: {
                    failure = true
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                }
            )
        } else {
            break
        }
        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
    DDLogDebug("Loaded new events")
}
```

It works great in the iOS9 simulator and on a iPhone5S w/ iOS9. 
But on an iPhone 4S with iOS8 there is a crash at the very end of the method :

`EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)` in `_dispatch_semaphore_dispose`

Any idea what would cause this and how could I fix this ?

Comment: If you wrapped the whole body in a dispatch_async block, what would happen?  Is it a possibility that the 4S just won't do it fast enough for the runtime to not think it is hung?  More of a guess, but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: My mistake, I could reproduce the bug with the iOS8 simulator.

Comment: I think the problem lies in coredata fetching. Can you try what @diatrevolo suggested?

Comment: removing the CoreData part does not solve the problem. The whole method is called on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was the problem : I did not leave the group on the `break`.

To fix it I called `dispatch_group_enter(group)` within the `if let` since it is not needed when I'm not doing an async call.